# How to disable loop unrolling in Rust?

Tags: performance, loops, rust

I am looking at Rust to rewrite a C++ codebase and I would like to know how to disable loop unrolling/vectorizing and control unroll count as well. In Clang we would use:

```
#pragma clang loop unroll(disable)
#pragma clang loop unroll(disable) vectorize(disable)
#pragma clang loop unroll_count(2)
```

It is highly performance sensitive code and not having control over loop codegen could be a showstopper.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot control how a given loop is/is not unrolled. It [has been proposed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2219), but no real progress has been made on considering such an RFC, much less accepting and implementing it.

---

If you are looking for very broad capabilities, you can pass `-C llvm-args=...` to the compiler to influence LLVM. If there's a way to disable loop unrolling completely, that *might* do what you want.

Pragmatically, I'd encourage you to get a [*walking skeleton*](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/712/what-is-a-walking-skeleton) of your code in Rust and see if the performance is acceptable. My personal experience has shown that "general" Rust code is more performant because of

- The borrow checker making it safe to be aggressive about using references instead of copies
- Comparatively easy usage of multithreading
- A strong type system that can help avoid performing work multiple times